# Javascript code to prevent special characters in otp input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have the following javscript code.I am trying to add the event codes from 48 to 57 for the special characters (! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) ).so that nothing happens in the text fields when typed.

```
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 116 || event.keyCode == 93 || event.keyCode == 33 ||
            event.keyCode == 34 || event.keyCode == 123 || event.keyCode == 154 ||
            event.keyCode == 82 || event.keyCode == 17 || event.keyCode === 38 ||
            event.keyCode === 40 || event.keyCode === 13 ||
            event.keyCode == 48 || event.keyCode == 49 || event.keyCode == 50 ||
            event.keyCode == 51 || event.keyCode == 52 || event.keyCode == 53 ||
            event.keyCode == 54 || event.keyCode == 55 || event.keyCode === 56 ||
            event.keyCode === 57
         ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The above code is not working for event codes 48 to 57. Whenever I try to type the special character in the input field am getting the number in the input fields

```
! for 1
@ for 2 
# for 3 
$ for 4
% for 5 
^ for 6
& for 7
* for 8
( for 9
) for 0
```

I am trying to find the solution and learn in the process. Thanks.

Comment: It would most likely be easier to invert the logic to only allow a specific character list (assuming 0-9 for OTP) and disallow anything else. There are lots of questions and tutorials already covering that

Comment: Can you provide a *snippet* that demonstrates the issue?  Your list of characters to numbers appears to be just unshifted US-keyboard layout for number keys.  As you're using `keydown` - you get the keycode, not the letter.   eg event.keyCode 49 = "1" but also "!" if shift is pressed - so to get `!` you hold shift and press "1" - giving keyCode = 49.   So your code, as is, *blocks* number keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hello a simple solution would be a regular expression.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?retiredLocale=de

```js
$(window).keydown(function (event) {
  if (/[!@#$%^&*()]/.test(event.key)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Try to enter the forbidden characters, you'll notice it doesn't work</p>
<input />
```